# How to "fix" object type returned after sql queries with Pandas read_sql_query

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes

I'm not sure how I should ask my question and the type of answers I'm expecting.

I'm querying MySQL with SQLAlchemy and Pandas. The query is working fine with expected output however all columns type are returned as `object`.

I need to take each columns a convert them to a specific format.

How should I handle this? Is this because the way I'm building my query? Or because of the database format?

Here is my code:

```
    q = "select id,user_id,date_create as date,value from db"

    df = pd.read_sql_query(q, connection)
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(df.info())
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
    df.id = df.id.astype('int64') 
    df.user_id = df.user_id.astype('int64') 
    df.value = df.value.astype('float64')
```

Comment: What are the types in your MySQL DB? If im not mistaking, `read_sql` should keep the data types as stored in the database.

Comment: just checked and it seems that data types are ok in the db.